# Folder of second hdd unaccessible for other users

Tags: finder, macos, permission

I have a Macbook pro with El Capitan and two HDDs. The second drive I wish to use as a sharing area with my wife who has a user on the same notebook.

I created a folder and put some files there. She can see but cannot modify the folder, can't save anything.

I opened the info window about the folder and there are 3 users: me, admin and everyone. I changed the permissions to all read and write and order to apply to content too.

Nothing has changed, my wife still cannot modify the contents of the folder, nor save files. "Everyone" should give rights to all users - a public folder. What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this second HDD, **Get Info** on the drive, and at the bottom, authenticate by clicking the lock button, then click the `Ignore ownership on this volume` checkbox.

[image]